# Three.js: loader.setPath is undefined

Tags: three.js

Hello developers and geniuses,

I am trying to simply import an obj-model to my three.js scene with WebGLrenderer.

I tried a lot of different tutorials but nothing worked for me. I always get the following error:

TypeError: loader.setPath is not a function. loader.setPath is undefined. The module that's getting the error is MTLLoader.js.

I implemented the js-File in my html head and of course I also did with three.min.js and OBJLoader.js.

I just don't know what to do. Can anyone help me and have a look at the specific code-piece?

> var mesh2 = null;
>
> var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader(); mtlLoader.setBaseUrl(
>   "myurlpath" ); mtlLoader.setPath(
>   "myurlpath" ); mtlLoader.load(
>   'WaltHead.mtl', function( materials ) {
>
> materials.preload();
>
> var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();   objLoader.setMaterials(
>   materials );   objLoader.setPath("myurlpath" );   objLoader.load(
>   'WaltHead.obj', function ( object ) {
>
> ```
> mesh2 = object;
> mesh2.position.y = -50;
> scene.add( mesh2 );
> ```
>
> } );
>
> } );

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Are you using the current release of the library and the loaders from that release? Use three.js, not three.min.js, for development.

Comment: loader is undefined can you post more snippet or the git version of your sample

Comment: I guess I found the issue... it seems to be a cross-origin error... I will provide more information soon.